# Calculate Continuous servo PWM Frequency and duty cycle

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pwm

- im using a Raspberry pi 2
- 2 x DS3115-360 servos

Im trying to get the frequency and duty cycle working correctly but I cant find the data sheet on this servo. 
I tried the typical 50hz 7.5 dc but it does not seem to be working for me.
I tried setting the duty cycle to 2.5 which does not even move the servo.
I tried using closer dc values like 6.8 and 7.8 which sometimes works by moving the servo very slowly and allot of stutter.
some times it will even start running faster at 7.5.
I thought it might be the RPI 5v ports so I used external power(5.8v) which gives me the same result.
Also the same result using only 1 motor at a time.

My Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
    
pwm1=GPIO.PWM(11, 50)
pwm2=GPIO.PWM(13, 50)
    
pwm1.start(0)
pwm2.start(0)
sleep(0.2)
GPIO.output(11, True)
GPIO.output(13, True)

def StopRotation(): 
    cycle = 7.5    
    print(cycle)
    pwm1.ChangeDutyCycle(cycle)
    pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(cycle)
    sleep(0.2)
def RotateClockwise(speed):  
    cycle = 7.5 - speed
    print(cycle)
    pwm1.ChangeDutyCycle(cycle)
    pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(cycle)
def RotateAntiClockwise(speed): 
    cycle = 7.5 + speed
    print(cycle)
    pwm1.ChangeDutyCycle(cycle)
    pwm2.ChangeDutyCycle(cycle)
RotateClockwise(0.8)
sleep(2)
StopRotation()
sleep(2)
RotateAntiClockwise(0.8)
sleep(2)
StopRotation()
GPIO.output(11, False)
GPIO.output(13, False) 
GPIO.cleanup()
```